# event values not passing to an imported file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export, event-listener

I'm trying to pass the innerHTML from an event from one `js` file to another `js` file that's on a different html page. Essentially I'm trying to create that site location you see on websites. `home` or `home > some-other-page-after-home`.

My initial html has about six links. They all go to different pages that are structured exactly the same but have different names and will have different info in them. So I'm trying to use the same html for all of them and not have to make six different html pages.

So what I did was, made an event listener that grabs the word of whatever link you are on. I've logged it to the console and it works fine. This is the **home** of this site. The next **layer** of the site is one of these six pages that all look the same.

I want the page to say `home > page1` or `home > page2` on the **next page** when you click on one of the six links and I want that **page1**/**page2** value to be the value that I get from this event listener.

I don't know if this is a practical way to approach this type of problem but it was the first idea I thought of. I have my event listener pass it's value to an object and then I have that object imported in another `js` file that the other html is linked to.

The problem is that when I get to the next page the object property `{name: e.target.innerHTML}` doesn't have a value anymore because in the context of that page `e.target.innerHTML` doesn't mean anything anymore. Or at least I think that's what the problem is.

Here are the scripts.

**choose-forum.js**

```js
let forum = document.querySelector('.column');

export let forumInfo  = {
    name: ""
};

const getForumName = (e) => {
    forumInfo.name = e.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(forumInfo.name);
}

forum.addEventListener('mouseover', getForumName);
```

**page2.js**

```js
import { forumInfo } from "./choose-forum.js";

let forumNav = document.querySelector('.forumNav');

const onLoad = () => {
 forumNav.innerHTML = forumInfo.name;
}

window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
```

logging `forumInfo.name` says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener'.

I'm assuming that's because `forumInfo.name` is equal to the event target that is triggered by the listener on the other file.

Any one know a way around this? I also thought about making the location bar a react component but I've just recently started working with react and I haven't learned routes or how to pass info to different pages with react so I figured I'd see if I could come up with something by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My thought as to why it wasn't working was correct. HTML is stateless and that. I found these nifty things called front end storages after trying an absurd amount of extremely convoluted things to make it work lol. I just had to rephrase my question in google to not mention imports and exports because the solution doesn't have anything to do with imports and exports.

---

Edit:

So basically I just stored the value that was generated by my mouseover event target in local storage. Which allowed me to access its value in another html file without using imports and exports which don't keep event information from other pages. The mouse over gets the innerHTML value of whatever it's hovering over and stores that value in local storage and then I set the site location bar in the next html page to that value in another js file. This causes problems if you just put the url into the search bar instead of clicking into it though since nothing is set to local storage. Or possibly the wrong value is set to local storage at the time that you navigate there. So I found another way that doesn't require local storages. I just put all the href values in my html to '/whatever' and then I create a get route for that path that sends the html file I have as sort of a template for all these pages. I then change the site location bar at the top of the page based on window.location by doing some manipulation and extracting just the part I need after local:host5000 and I set the value to that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).